# erlang - startup script

Tags: erlang

To start my program I do the next sequence:

```
$ erl
> c(module1).
> c(module2).
> c(modulen).
modulen:start().
```

Is there any possibility to create script that allow me to launch my program ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a loader script that takes care of starting your application in an OTP fashion:

```
-module(XYZ_app).

-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    application:start(inets),
    application:start(XYZ).
```

You launch that script through a shell script. Beware of using `escript` if you plan on building daemons running at the OS boot time as they are tricky.

```
#!/bin/bash
erl -boot start_sasl -s XYZ_app start
```

Of course you need your `XYZ.app` file (just an example):

```
{application, tinycouch,
 [{description, "tinycouch"},
  {vsn, "0.1"},
  {modules, [
         tinycouch, tinycouch_app, tinycouch_sup,
         tinycouch_server, tinycouch_logger_h, tinycouch_utils,
         tinycouch_db, mod_tinycouch
        ]},
  {registered, [tinycouch
            ,tinycouch_server
            ,tinycouch_sup
           ]},
  {applications, [kernel, stdlib, sasl, inets]},
  {env, []},

  %% Application Start point
  {mod, {tinycouch_sup, []}}]}.
```

... and all your `.erl` files must have been compiled.

**Note** that if you intend to distribute your application (e.g. Debian repository etc), you probably should consider having a `make` file to compile and install your app.

As a final note: you could also go with a `boot` file (the ultimate OTP way) but I find those very constraining: a boot file ties your application to **specific** version release of Erlang (and other dependent applications). Your application might be able to run in various Erlang releases but you will need to have a separate build/release process for each "platform release" you intend to ship for.

Comment: You mean XYZ_app as in: "erl -boot start_sasl -s XYZ_app start", and 'start' is the default if omitted.

Comment: Boot files don't have to be constraining. I use a make file with a make boot target that rebuilds the boot file for the currently available erlang distribution. And boot files do make starting a service dead easy.

Comment: @Jeremy Wall: your method sort of defeats the purpose then.

Comment: not really. Boot files have just one purpose. Describe a startup environment for your app. *.rel files which are used to create the boot file have multiple purposes one of which is to describe a release for your app. I may be a little liberal with that purpose but the ease of startup with the boot file is more than useful enough to warrant it.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile the modules with `erlc`

```
erlc module1 module2 module3
```

You can also create a script to run you program

```
#!/usr/bin/escript

main(_) ->
    modulen:start().
```

Then in the console:

```
chmod +x start.erl
./start.erl
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways

precompile your code

```
$ erlc module1.erl
$ erl -s module1 funcname arg1 arg2 ....
```

Or use escript

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
main() ->
    module1:fun(...)
```

escript is a scripting interface to Erlang

Answer (score 1):

You can use `erl -make` directly, as it assumes all `*.erl` files should be compiled to `*.beam`, and skip it if they haven't been changed since last compile. Check out the [make module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html) for what you can put in your `Emakefile` to change certain behavior.

Using plain `Makefile` to invoke this compile strategy also gives other users a familiar build-procedure.

Having a bootstrap start function as jldupont suggests is a nice way to start up your development environment. It is even sufficiently fine for using in production to some point.

The next step is to use full OTP (`*.rel`) release files and generate boot scripts that starts all the applications in the order the `*.app` specify dependencies on each other.

Answer (score 1):

In the home directory, create file
**.erlang**

in that file write

```
compile:file(/path-to/module1).
compile:file(/path-to/module2).
compile:file(/edit-real-path-to/modulen). % etcetera; do not use c(module) inside this file!
```

then, if you need add (inside .erlang):

```
module1:start(). % etc
```

When you run erl (in the shell), the content of the .erlang (provided this file is in the home dir) will be executed at start (of the interpreter-erlang-VM you launch).

You can create .erlang file in some other (some 'current') directory, then, if you run erl (erlang interpreter) in that directory, that another .erlang will override the content of that .erlang in the home dir (of that which is like /home/your-user-name/.erlang ).

It is good idea to write inside of .erlang some reminder, like

```
io:format(".erlang loaded-compiled module1!\n"). %etc
```

(as not to forget about that code which otherwise will be executed silently !)

(also, you can check, for this case, that e.g. module1 is indeed compiled and loaded after start, this or some similar way:

```
AllLoaded = code:all_loaded().
lists:filter(fun({Module,_})-> Module =:= module1 end, AllLoaded).
```

the answer should be like:
[{module1,"/home/your-user-name/(path-to-your-code)/module1.beam"}]
)

Answer (score -1):

Check out Sinan and Faxien: http://www.erlware.org